# Passing a c++ vector to python and back

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, numpy, python-embedding

I am using a c++ code to do some simulations on an image. At some point, I need to label the image clusters, for which I want to use python `ndimage.label` (because it is almost 10 times faster than my labelling code). However, I am very new to python and have no idea how to pass the arguments (image) to python from C++. The search so far has given no results

1. in the C++ code, the image is stored as `vector<vector<int>>`
2. The python code needs the image as `ndarray`
3. I would like to convert the output labelled array (`ndarray`) from python to a `vector<vector<int>>` again

Can anyone please suggest how can this be achieved. To begin with, any suggestions will do, although computational time is a big concern for me

Comment: In terms of speed, how much overhead will it be to convert the variables back and forth between c++ and python everytime I want to label. From your reply it seems as if the variable is passed by reference between C++ and python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my library https://github.com/jzwinck/pccl/blob/master/NumPyArray.hpp to create a NumPy array from C++ using existing data e.g. from a vector.  And any changes made in Python will be reflected in C++.  It depends on Boost.Python, but the core code is simple and uses the NumPy C API directly so you could also extract just that part (the key is `PyArray_NewFromDescr`).